# "pythonic" method to parse a string of comma-separated integers into a list of integers?

Tags: python

I am reading in a string of integers such as `"3 ,2 ,6 "` and want them in the list `[3,2,6]` as integers.  This is easy to hack about, but what is the "pythonic" way of doing it?

Answer (score 32):

```
mylist = [int(x) for x in '3 ,2 ,6 '.split(',')]
```

And if you're not sure you'll only have digits (or want to discard the others):

```
mylist = [int(x) for x in '3 ,2 ,6 '.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()]
```

Comment: I think you have it a bit backwards: `'3,2,6'.split(',')`

Comment: @orangeoctopus It works fine anyway, `int` discard surrounding whitespace

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I wanted to add to it. if someone needs to validate the input before casting it to an int() (which will throw an exception if you dont) then you can just add `if x.isdigit()` right at the end

Comment: @JohnRuddell added that into my answer

Comment: FWIW, `.isdigit` is fine if you don't need to handle negative integers.

Answer (score 25):

```
map( int, myString.split(',') )
```

Comment: @Matt: actually, while personally I love the functional style, list comprehensions are more Pythonic

Comment: Is there any way for, s="a,b;c,d" to sList=[['a','b'],['c','d']] ?

Comment: In Python 3, you'd have to wrap that in a `list` call because `map` returns an iterator not a list. Thus: `list(map(int, my_string.split(',')))`

Answer (score 9):

While a custom solution will teach you about Python, for production code using the `csv` module is the best idea. Comma-separated data can become more complex than initially appears.

Comment: @Anurag: "teach him to fish..." - ever heard that fable? It's what I'm trying to do here. Just parsing a string of commas is rarely *the* task one attempts to solve, behind this there are more complex requirements. If I'm wrong, no harm done, other answers provide the simpler approach

Comment: @katrielalex, the OP said, "I'm reading in a string of integers...". For a robust solution it's better to use the csv module as Eli recommends, of course.

Comment: @Eli, i have heard that fable, but sometimes for a very specific problems, we need not use complex solutions, like using csv module to read a list of integers