# Python - Convert string with numbers into a list of integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer, type-conversion

I've read several questions about this on SO, however, none of them worked out for me - I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I have a string with numbers separated with commas and spaces which looks like this:

```
my_string = '32, 76, 82, 19, 25'
```

Now what I would like to have is a list of integers of the numbers in the string above, so I can extract single integers from it like this:

```
print my_list[2]
>>>82
```

or

```
print my_list[4]
>>>25
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've read several questions and they didn't work then show your efforts

Comment: The delimeter you have is ', ' use that to split your numbers in to a list.
integs = [int(x) for x in my_string.split(', ')]

Comment: my_list = map(lambda x: int(x), my_string.split(','))

Comment: @BPL The lambda is unnecessary, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3477535/4014959 (and my comment on that answer).

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, yeah, thx. Also, to get the same result with py2/3 maybe you should do `list(map(int, my_string.split(',')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the problem into two parts.

1 Split the text into a list with the data you need and filter the other.

```
num_list = my_string.split(',')
```

2 Convert the data into what type you want it

```
integers = [int(x) for x in num_list]
```

Then you might clean it up

```
integs = [int(x) for x in my_string.split(',')]
```

Comment: You can make this more general by passing `','` as the arg to `.split` because `int` ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didnt think of that

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way would be

```
[int(i) for i in my_string.split(',')]
```

Of course you can build a simple for loop if you prefer, like

```
mylist = []
for i in my_string.split(','):
    mylist.append(int(i))
```

There are plenty of possibilities