# Dealing with mixed datatypes

Tags: python

On taking the input 1,2,3,4,5
initially python will consider it as a string datatype,

But if we try to convert the numbers to integer using `int()` we'll encounter another problem as a commas cannot be converted into integer format

What will be the most appropriate way to convert the numbers into integer and keep the commas in the string format itself

Note: input cannot be changed in anyways

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477502/pythonic-method-to-parse-a-string-of-comma-separated-integers-into-a-list-of-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["pythonic" method to parse a string of comma-separated integers into a list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477502/pythonic-method-to-parse-a-string-of-comma-separated-integers-into-a-list-of-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Output:

```
# input : 1 2 3 4 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or:

```
str_num = "1,2,3,4,5"
list(map(int, str_num.split(',')))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```